# how to install Windows on NVMe disc and boot loader or other disc

Tags: windows-7, windows, bootloader

I have a problem with NVMe disc.

I need to run windows on Intel 750 NVMe disc, but my motherboard doesn't support NVMe boot.

I have second sata drive.

Is there any way to install windows on Intel 750, and bootloader on another disc?

Comment: No;  What you want without new hardware is not possible.  Your hardware does not support what you want to do.

Comment: Incorrect. It is certainly possible, how hard it is depends on whether or not the NVMe disk is accessible from Windows PE. Does the Windows installer see the drive?

Comment: Yep, it see the drive without problem. I just cannot boot from that drive. However i have sata hdd in that computer. availble for boot loader install.

Comment: Hi. Have you managed to boot the NVMe drive with a bootloader on the sata drive? I am in the same boat as you, but I'd like to know prior to spend money for the NVMe ssd. Thanks!!